# Rotate ImageView without clipping

Tags: android, imageview, scale, image-rotation

I want to change rotation dynamically, bud i faced with the problem. I did simple code example of my problem

as you can see parent cuts off piece of my image view when i set rotate

[click here to see emulator screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZMB9.png)

xml very simple

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:rotation="-10"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Actually I want my picture to scale and not go beyond the boundaries of the ImageView
I tried to find solution, but all of them didn't resolve my problem
[image how i want to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7u7Td.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use parent layout for ImageView and set background:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/teal_200">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:rotation="-10"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for answer!
but i use more difficult background which needed to rotate with image.
In my case i added margin so avoid clipping, but i still  really want to find way to rotate my imageView content without clipping